# Java packaging and import - where is my error?

Tags: java, import, package, syntax-error

Trying to learn Java from Bruce Eckel's book, I don't understand why the compiler doesn't find the library I want to import. I have first done this on Windows/Cygwin and now on Centos 7, using OpenJDK 1.8.0. Same result on both platforms.

This line:

```
import static t.b.u.*;
```

causes compiler error

```
$ javac TestPrint.java
TestPrint.java:2: error: package t.b does not exist
import static t.b.u.*;
                 ^
```

I agree that package *t.b* doesn't exist, but I actually wanted to import package *t.b.u*. Why does the compiler ignore the u?

CLASSPATH is set as follows:

```
$ export|grep CLASS
declare -x CLASSPATH="/home/bbausch/thinking-in-java"
```

The package is a single file:

```
$ cat /home/bbausch/thinking-in-java/t/b/u/Print.java

package t.b.u;
import java.io.*;

public class Print {
... etc ...
```

The error is probably so obvious that I don't see it. Can somebody help?

Comment: Lets first remove the `static` from `import static` since it doesn't seem right there.

Comment: When removing `static`, the compiler doesn't complain about the package, but it can't find the symbols defined in the package. The symbols are all static methods.

Comment: Methods are defined in classes, not packages. If you want to import them statically you need to point out class which contains it like `import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specifically related to the Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3

These two lines inherently ask for different things:

```
import static t.b.u.*;
```

This statement asks to import all static methods from **a class** named `u` from **a package** `t.b`.

```
import t.b.u.*;
```

This statement asks to import all classes underneath `t.b.u`.

Static imports target a TypeName only. Normal imports target a package, or a specific class.

The roughly equivalent general import to the static import would be this:

```
import t.b.u;
```

This asks to import just the class `u` from a package `t.b`.

In your specific example, you'd probably want this statement to import all static methods of the Print class.

```
import static t.b.u.Print.*;
```

Comment: Yes. After changing the line to `import static t.b.u.Print.*` (`Print` being the name of the class), the compiler is happy. So am I, but it's too late in the day here for my brain to understand why static imports are treated differently. It's only now that I see that Eckel does it exactly like that. As I said, too obvious for me to see the error. Thanks a million!

Comment: Static imports are usually used for helper methods where constantly invoking the static class' name is a hassle, like Application Constants. Instead of doing `ApplicationConstants.NAME` you could just use `NAME` in another class.

Comment: @Compass (re: `import static t.b.u.Print;`) static import are meant for static members so we need to point out *which* members from class we want to import. We can do it by explicitly specifying that we want to `import static some.ClassName.methodName;` or that we want to import *all* static members from class via `import static some.ClassName.*;`. In other words you probably want to add `.*` at the end, before `;` :)